# How can i set autocomplete to off

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete

i have my own selector with autocomplete.
How can i set onv-selector autocomplete="off" ?

```html
<v-autocomplete v-else
                        outline
                        ref="select"
                        slot="activator"
                        v-bind:loading ="loading"
                        v-bind:label="label"
</v-autocomplete>
```

xport default {
        props: ['caption', 'autocomplete']}

Comment: Do you want to use v-autocomplete as a simple select box?

Comment: in my v-select i havent got any autocomplete option. but when i start my aplication, the v-select show information as he have option autocomplete